# R - Selecting the values of a column based on the values of another row

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this

```
City          TreeID    Age   Diameter
City_1             X      1          6
City_1             Y      2          5 
City_2             Y      3          5 
City_3             X      4         10
```

I have a variable `nominal` that can be `"TreeId"`, `"Age"` or `Diameter` and another variable `city` that has the name of a city stored in string format.
I want to be able to pick up only the values of the column `nominal` for the correct city name

An example :  `city = "City_1"` and `nominal = "Age"`, then I should only pick up the values `1` and `2`

I searched on here but nothing I could find was adapted to my case because I use variables so I don't know in advance which column I want to choose. I am lost, any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function to do that.

```
return_value <- function(data, city, nominal) {
  data[data$City == city, nominal]  
}

return_value(df, 'City_1', 'Age')
#[1] 1 2

return_value(df, 'City_2', 'Diameter')
#[1] 5
```

Comment: Thanks ! Now what if I had a second nominal variable named nominal2 ? By that I mean I would want to pick only the value form the column nominal1 if nominal2 satisfies some condition

Answer (score 1):

You coul use `pull`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(City == "City_1") %>% 
  pull(Age)

df %>% 
  filter(City == "City_1") %>% 
  pull(Diameter)
```

```
[1] 1 2

[1] 6 5
```